# Reputation Suddenly decreasing day by day

Tags: support, reputation

I used to have around 1050 reputation,when i logged in now its showing 1030 but no activity in reputation details.

Attached the screenshot of my profile.

Any insight into this issue will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the "show removed posts" checkbox? Please read [How do I read the history of my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

Comment: Where can i find show removed posts checkbox ?

Comment: Did you read the post I linked?

Comment: Yes,http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation#answer-139615.but i cannot find the mentioned checkbox to filter out

Comment: Got it man !!..2 of my answers were converted to comments..Thanks for the help!